# Core Data WAL mode not persisting changes to .db, only .db-wal and .db-shm

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

So, I have been using MagicalRecord to develop an iPad app, and recently after moving to an auto-migrating store I have been experiencing some issues. I need to sync my .db file from one device over to another, so I need all of the data to be in the .db, but it seems like with WAL journaling mode enabled (the default for Magical Record auto-migrating stores) no matter how I save it only persists the changes to either the .db-wal or the .db-shm files. I switched to a normal sqlite store and everything worked fine. So, my question is, with WAL journaling enabled do I need to do anything special to actually get Core Data to save to the main database, or will I just have to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the journal mode. You have the [Magical Record source](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/39e2523d43b0fba0a90f66bdc59e9c73d74d911a/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator%2BMagicalRecord.m#L134), after all. Change the SQLite journal mode to `DELETE`, and the journal mode will be deleted after every transaction. Disabling journalling is a really bad idea, don't do that. But using a different mode should be fine.

Core Data does not offer any API for manipulating the journal once the persistent store is open. SQLite is an implementation detail, and Core Data doesn't expose the internal SQLite details. The closest you can get is the `options` parameter when setting up the Core Data stack, which is where you can change the journal mode (and where MR changes it).

Comment: Ok, I think I will do this. Just need to figure out the best way to save my changes to MagicalRecord with CocoaPods. Thanks!

Comment: While this works, I am still at a loss to figure out why the file grows in the first place with CoreData. It might be an implementation detail but unless there is a very specific reason to have multiple readers on the same file it should never EVER grow. I've been unable to find any solution to this problem, as journal_mode=DELETE isn't actually a solution, its a workaround with very severe downsides.

Answer (score 0):

The `-wal` file is part of the database; you must synchronize it together with the `.db` file.

Alternatively, you can copy the data to the main database file by executing a [checkpoint](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt).

Comment: When using Core Data you don't have access to the direct SQLite handle, so there's no way to perform a checkpoint manually (or indeed to use any `sqlite3_*` call).